# US Interracial Marriages

Tags: data-request, us-census

I'm trying to find data that:

- is from the US **AND**
- from 1980 **AND** somewhat recent (within ten years) **AND**
- Interracial Marriages--Race/Ethnicity of the two people involved

I'm trying to look on the Census site but it's  getting overwhelming.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge (not authoritative, but based on a good bit of Census data experience), there are no general Census tabulations which break down the reported races of different people in a single household, whether spouses, children, or other.  Generally, those details are rolled up in aggregate counts of people.  There are a couple of ACS tables which get at the race of the householder, but not in comparison to the race of other people living in that household.

I've found a few reports generated by Census Bureau employees or other people who have privileged access to the data.

- [This page](https://www.census.gov/population/www/socdemo/interrace.html) presents a few tables for 1970-1990, with bits of data going back to 1960 and up to 1992.
- [This more recent report](https://www.census.gov/library/stories/2018/07/interracial-marriages.html) compares data from 2000 to the 2012-2016 American Community Survey.

Pew Research Center did [a substantial study on interracial marriage in 2017](https://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2017/05/18/intermarriage-in-the-u-s-50-years-after-loving-v-virginia/). You might take a look at the methodology section of their full PDF report for more on how they went about it.